# How to convert Figure object to a Numpy array with RGBA values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, plotly, reportlab

I have Plotly Figure object which i have created figure using Plotly. I want to convert this Figure object to Numpy Array. So that i can then convert this array data to PIL Image object. And them drawImage on Reportlab using .drawImage method.

Here, b is Plotly Figure object.

```
def fig2data ( b ):
    """
    @brief Convert a Plotly figure to a 4D numpy array with RGBA channels and return it
    @param fig a plotly figure
    @return a numpy 3D array of RGBA values
    """
    # draw the renderer
    fig.canvas.draw ( )
    # Get the RGBA buffer from the figure
    w,h = fig.canvas.get_width_height()
    buf = numpy.fromstring ( fig.canvas.tostring_argb(), dtype=numpy.uint8 )
    buf.shape = ( w, h,4 )
    # canvas.tostring_argb give pixmap in ARGB mode. Roll the ALPHA channel to have it in RGBA mode
    buf = numpy.roll ( buf, 3, axis = 2 )
    return buf

buf = fig2data(b)
buf
```

Which gives me

```
AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'canvas'
```

I am using following library:

```
import pandas
import numpy
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from PIL import Image
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, SimpleDocTemplate, Spacer, Image, Flowable
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your setup or imports, but if all is good, your issue might be that you need to attach the canvas to the figure. This is done by using FigureCanvasAgg:

```
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg

    def fig2data ( b ):
        """
        @brief Convert a Matplotlib figure to a 4D numpy array with RGBA channels 
         and return it
        @param fig a matplotlib figure
        @return a numpy 3D array of RGBA values
        """

        canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)
        # draw the renderer
        fig.canvas.draw ( )
        # Get the RGBA buffer from the figure
        w,h = fig.canvas.get_width_height()
        buf = numpy.fromstring ( fig.canvas.tostring_argb(), dtype=numpy.uint8 )
        buf.shape = ( w, h,4 )
        # canvas.tostring_argb give pixmap in ARGB mode. Roll the ALPHA channel to 
         have it in RGBA mode
        buf = numpy.roll ( buf, 3, axis = 2 )
        return buf

    buf = fig2data(b)
    buf
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello @KathyJones, This gives me `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'set_canvas'`.

Comment: can you share what libraries you're importing? Also the detailed error report.

Comment: I have added that in question.